# Which threads exactly are CPU bound

Tags: c++, multithreading

I heard that the optimal amount of threads depends on whether they are CPU bound or not. But what exactly does it mean?

Suppose that the most time my threads will sleep via `Sleep` function from WinAPI. Should I considered such threads as non-CPU bound and increase their amount over the CPU cores count?

Comment: Why are your threads mostly `Sleep`ing? But yes, those threads are definitely not CPU bound.

Comment: @Gregor McGregor But most of the instructions depends on the memory they are operating

Comment: @Gregor McGregor Ah, in non-CPU bound instructions we're depending on the memory outside registers and fast cache such as files, network devices etc?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "optimal". Is "optimal" equivalent to "all CPUs 100% busy all the time"? Or is it "every thread completes its job in a minimum amount of wall-clock time"? Either one could be considered optimal, just by different metrics - optimal usage of expensive CPU resources for maximum return on investment vs optimal progress toward achieving processing goals...

Comment: How about searching the web? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cpu-bound&ia=about does provide an answer, for example.

Comment: Since a thread that is sleeping does not get any useful work done, you should try to keep the number of such threads to the minimum. Ideally, you would only have one. Say you have two threads sleeping, one to do X and one to do Y. Why would that be preferable to having just one thread sleeping that would then do X or Y? Having multiple threads just to wait for specific things makes as little sense as having two people to wait for either of two telephones to ring. Unless they ring so much that you're basically not waiting, one person waiting is enough.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, is this why I have to spend ages on call line nowadays? Because someone optimized person-to-telephone ratio? :) Joking aside, in real-time systems you might want to have several idle threads, where each of them waits on it's unique condition.

Comment: @SergeyA His threads are sleeping, not waiting for any particular condition. I do agree that sometimes you have a condition that you need a thread to wait for. But here, all threads are waiting on the very same condition, some amount of time to pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thread is bound by a resource if it spends most of its time using it, and thus its speed is bound by the speed of that resource.

Given the above definition, a thread is CPU bound if its most used resource is the computing power of the CPU, that is, it's a thread that does heavy computation. You gain nothing from putting more of these than there are available cores, because they will compete for CPU time.

You can (instead) put more threads than available cores when the threads are bound by other resources (most commonly files), because they will spend most time waiting for those to be ready, and thus leave the CPU available for other threads.

A thread that spends most time sleeping does not use the CPU very much, and thus it is not CPU bound.

EDIT: examples of non-CPU bound threads are threads that read files, wait for network connections, talk to PCI connected devices, spend most time waiting on condition variables and GUI threads that wait for user input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I get another examples of non-CPU bound stuff? Maybe network operations?